# A simple reducer that share a value and a dispatch to my components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Edited question :**

I think i don't really well explained my self in the *old question* below so I am rewriting it.

So basically I want to do something like a module that have a default value (for example a string), anywhere in my project I need to be able to access to this value and modifie it via importing this module.

When the value of this module is changed, my components should be re-render. This is why in my example in the *old question* I've tried to use `useState`, but it doesn't work because it recreate the state every time the module is called.

---

**Old question :**

I am trying to create a reducer that keep an object, share this object, and a dispatch that permit me to change this object.

Here is my reducer, he's really simple but for my needs I thought it would be enough (but maybe the problem is not  coming from here) :

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default () => useState({ foo: 'bar' });
```

And here is how I try to use it :

```
// Component that show the content of `foo`
import myReducer from '../reducers/MyReducer';

export default = () => {
  const [anObject] = myReducer();
  return <h1>foo : {anObject}</h1>;
};
```

```
// Component that set `foo`'s value
import myReducer from '../reducers/MyReducer';

export default = () => {
  const [anObject, setAnObject] = myReducer();
  return <button onClick={() => setAnObject({ ...anObject, foo: 'newBar' })}>Dispatch the reducer</button>;
};
```

And when I try this in the browser I get this error :

```
Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

In this case the whole reducer is a little bit useless but imagine multiples components like the last one that set the `foo`'s value.

I could pass everything through props but this is just an example, it could not be really viable to do this on a big project.

I am referring to this part of the doc : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Comment: A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use”

Comment: @MohamedRamrami That's right, this is just a name for the example. I will edit this question because I realized that it isn't really clear.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the context API ("Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level."). https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: @MohamedRamrami Is it possible to change the value of a `useContext` and re-render when it change ?

> "I need to be able to access to this value and modifie it."

> "When the value of this module is changed, my components should be re-render."

Comment: Yes, read more here https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component

Comment: Or you can use a global state management lib like redux